# TypeScript extends keyword returns different result when used with/without generics

Tags: typescript

Consider this TS snippet

```
type Check<T, U> = T extends U ? 1 : 0;
type Check2<T> = T extends 'a' ? 1 : 0;

type C = Check<'a' | 'b', 'a'> // 0 | 1
type C2 = Check2<'a' | 'b'> // 0 | 1
type C3 = 'a' | 'b' extends 'a' ? 1 : 0; // 0
```

[Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgFhAxgawDwBUA0UCqA%20KAXinSggA9gIA7AEwGdcoB%20KARigC4oAGAbgBQoSLAQoATBgLFSFKnUYByAIaKW7Lr0FDw0GEVFI0KtQB8oigEaLsJggHp7vKObY6RMcQfhHJJlxbWDk48AW7CegDMBv7mVmpyNAwWquoc3PxQjrwCQA)

I'm a bit confused with such typescript behavior. I thought types C, C2, C3 have to be equal but they are not. It seems that for cases with generics (types C, C2) TS iterates
through the union type and returns the result for every literal type in the union, but in the last case it checks the whole union against the right part of the extends keyword.

Is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: No worries, burned me too first time I encountered it. I understand why it is the way it is but it is definitely counter-intuitive at first.